# Emoticon keyboard on iphone, not emoji

Tags: iphone

How to have a keyboard that presents shortcuts for common ascii emoticons?

I specifically do NOT want anything that uses the emoji unicode symbols. But instead a keyboard that provides shortcuts for the standard emoticons such as `:-)`, `:-(`, `;-)`, `B-)`, `:-*`, `<3`, and so on.

Update: so far, it seems there is no way to do what I ask for. So I asked a [more specific question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25047/what-sms-apps-exist-on-the-iphone-that-support-ascii-emoticons-not-emoji) asking for SMS apps that support ASCII emoticons.

Comment: There isn't an official door that apple has provided to make this possible. You could jailbreak the device (generally not my cup of tea) or use some composition app like [TextExpander](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textexpander/id326180690?mt=8) to do the job and then paste the results using the clipboard. A poor solution for snippets as short as you propose, but the best option I currently see to your dilemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Apple doesn't allow for third-party keyboards outside of apps, you'd have to find (or make) an app that does what you want and design your own keyboard to do that.

Comment: This was correct at the time, but now Apple does allow third party keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up shortcuts under Settings → General → Keyboards → Shortcuts.
For example you could set up a shortcut as follows:

phrase = `:-]`
shortcut = `sml`

Answer (score 0):

If you add Japanese Kana or Chinese simplified keyboards there is a smiley face button with a bunch of ascii art smiley faces, but they're not exactly the "standard emoticons" that you refer to.

Eg.

(T_T)\(^-^)